# Exporting data using solr streaming expressions is randomly not working

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I am using solr 7.4 version. I am trying to export data using streaming expressions.

Following is the simple curl query that i am using. I am indexing my data and testing the following query.

```
curl --data-urlencode 'expr=search(collection1,
                                   q="text:solar",              
                                   fl="id",
                                   sort="id asc",
                                   qt="/export")' http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/stream
```

when i run above query with initial few documents indexed, it is working fine. After indexing few thousand documents (around , i am getting the following error for the same query.

```
EXCEPTION":"java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: --> http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/: An exception has occurred on the server, refer to server log for details."
```

I've looked into my solr logs and the following is the error info

java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: --> http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/: An exception has occurred on the server, refer to server log for details.
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.stream.CloudSolrStream.openStreams(CloudSolrStream.java:400)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.stream.CloudSolrStream.open(CloudSolrStream.java:275)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.stream.ExceptionStream.open(ExceptionStream.java:54)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.StreamHandler$TimerStream.open(StreamHandler.java:397)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.stream.TupleStream.writeMap(TupleStream.java:83)
    at org.apache.solr.response.JSONWriter.writeMap(JSONResponseWriter.java:539)
    at org.apache.solr.response.TextResponseWriter.writeVal(TextResponseWriter.java:181)
    at org.apache.solr.response.JSONWriter.writeNamedListAsMapWithDups(JSONResponseWriter.java:209)
    at org.apache.solr.response.JSONWriter.writeNamedList(JSONResponseWriter.java:325)
    at org.apache.solr.response.JSONWriter.writeResponse(JSONResponseWriter.java:120)
    at org.apache.solr.response.JSONResponseWriter.write(JSONResponseWriter.java:71)
    at org.apache.solr.response.QueryResponseWriterUtil.writeQueryResponse(QueryResponseWriterUtil.java:65)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.writeResponse(HttpSolrCall.java:787)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:524)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:377)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:323)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1634)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:678)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: --> http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/: An exception has occurred on the server, refer to server log for details.
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.stream.CloudSolrStream.openStreams(CloudSolrStream.java:394)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: --> http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/: An exception has occurred on the server, refer to server log for details.
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.stream.SolrStream.read(SolrStream.java:225)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.stream.CloudSolrStream$TupleWrapper.next(CloudSolrStream.java:484)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.stream.CloudSolrStream$StreamOpener.call(CloudSolrStream.java:507)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.stream.CloudSolrStream$StreamOpener.call(CloudSolrStream.java:494)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:209)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: JSONTupleStream: expected OBJECT_START but got EOF
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.stream.JSONTupleStream.expect(JSONTupleStream.java:99)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.stream.JSONTupleStream.advanceToDocs(JSONTupleStream.java:179)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.stream.JSONTupleStream.next(JSONTupleStream.java:77)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.stream.SolrStream.read(SolrStream.java:194)
    ... 8 more

Is it because new documents have something unusual in their content? Even if that is the case, i am requesting only one field which is **id** and there is nothing unusual about it.

```
Also, to mention, if i give q="*:*" it is working fine (which is kind of weird)
```

Any idea what what is issue here ?

Comment: Do you have a single or multiple nodes?

Comment: @MatsLindh: I've multiple shards but on same machine.